# how to reset javascript variable declared by keyword var?

Tags: javascript, variables, var

I have an 'init' function in which i have  few variables which i want to set as undefined/null on logout event.

```
var EmpCode;
function initChat(user, usertoken, ip){ 
  if(user!= null){
    EmpCode = user;
    var time_id = Date.now();
//some function calls.
}

function logout(){
//reset variable
}
```

i want to reset 'EmpCode' variable value on on logout function.

`delete EmpCode;` does not seems to work because it is defined by keyword var.

Comment: `delete` just works on properties, what do you mean with reset? you can set it like this `EmpCode = undefined`. If you declare it like this `var EmpCode;` its automatically undefined at this point

Answer (score 2):

```
function logout(){
  //reset variable
  EmpCode = undefined; // or null
}
```